# distribution probability question involving binary functions for certain n<2^10

Tags: combinatorics, binary

For any positive integer n, let G(n) be the number of pairs of adjacent bits in the binary representation of n which are different. For example, G(10)=3 because the bits of $1010_2$ change at all three places and G(12)=1 because the bits of $1100_2$ change only from the fours to the twos place.

For how many positive integers $n<2^{10}$ is it true that G(n)=2?

Can someone give me any hints or point me in the right direction? I am supposed to use distribution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have ten bits and two "barriers": the digit changes when you hit a barrier.  So you have to place two barriers within 2 of 9 possible slots.  (A barrier can't be at the very end of the number, nor before the beginning. For an $n$ bit number (starting with first bit $1$) we thus have  $\binom{n-1}{2}$.

But be careful of two things:  The two barriers can't touch (that subtracts off $n-1$.  And if the number is less than $2^9$ it is only $9$ bits and so forth, so you get a sum of 
these binomial coefficients.

Comment: So if I am understanding you correctly: would I then have to find all n < 2^10 such that C(n-1, 2) = 2? @MarkFischler

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't consider leading zeroes, so the first digit of a number will always be an `1`. If $G(n)=2$, then the *last* digit is `1` too.

Now imagine that you extend all of your $n$s with leading zeroes until it has exactly 11 bits. The first bit will be `0`, and the bit will change *three* times if $G(n)=2$.

Now there are ten possible places where the bit can change. Will every choice of three of these places (together with the rule that the first bit is `0` and the last is `1`) lead to a distinct number with $G(n)=2$?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the term "bit"...can you explain?

Comment: @MathyPerson: Um, you're using it yourself in the question ...?

Comment: Never mind, I looked it up. A "bit" means 10 or 01, right?

Comment: @MathyPerson: A bit is a binary digit, i.e. either `0`or `1`.

Comment: When you mentioned "with the rule that the first bit is 0 and the last is 1" in your Op, did you mean to say that the first bit is *1* and the last i 1?

Comment: I forgot to ask. Are all the numbers in base 2?

Comment: @Mathy: Yes, "binary" means base 2. No, I do mean that the first bit is 0. Numbers less than $2^{10}$ have up to ten bits, but I'm suggesting adding 0's to the left of them until there are eleven bits in total. E.g., the number twelve would be represented as $00000001100_2$.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly (looking from Mark Fischler's input as well): Numbers in between 2^9 and 2^10 will have 10 bits. Numbers less than 2^9 will have 9 bits. Numbers less than 2^8 will have 8 bits, etc., until we have "numbers less than 2^1 will have 1 bit. Those are all of our cases, and we have to find the possible configurations in each case (will turn out as a binominal coefficient) and add them all together?

Comment: @Mathy: Yes, except my idea here is to consolidate all those cases by into one by writing the numbers with more bits than necessary, just like "twelve" can be written in decimal as 12 or 00012.

Comment: But isn't 00012 invalid? Wouldn't it give us 2*2^0 + 1*2^1 instead?

Comment: @MathyPerson: The 00012 example is in decimal, i.e. the usual everyday base-ten. It was just meant to show that adding leading zeroes is not something specific to binary.

Comment: Referring to Mark Fischler's answer. Does that mean that for a 10 bit number (the absolute maximum # of bits), it would be $C(9,2)$-8?

Comment: @MathyPerson: Which "it"? My answer to the original question is still $\binom{10}{3}$.

Comment: I don't believe I mentioned "it"?

Comment: @MathyPerson: "...(the absolute maximum # of bits), **it** would be..."

Comment: Using what Mark Fischler said: I tried $C(9,2)-9  + C(8,2)-8 + C(7,2) -7 + C(6,2) -6 + C(5, 2) - 5 + C(4, 2) - 4 + C(3, 2) - 3 + C (2, 2) - 2$ and got 76, but C(10,3) yields 120. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. By it, I meant "the possible configurations for a 10 bit number"

Comment: @MathyPerson: I don't get why you're subtracting 9, 8, 7, and so forth.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I just reread Mark's answer. When he mentioned "subtracting off n-1", he was referring to the n-1 in $C(n-1,2)$. If I just have $C(9,2)+C(8,2)+C(7,2)+C(6,2)+C(5,2)+C(4,2)+C(3,2)+C(2,2)$, the answer is 120 as well. :)